# How to fit a smooth curve on a plot with very few points in R

Tags: r, plot, loess

I have just 4 data points:

```
points = c(60, 46, 46, 60)
```

that "want" to describe a parabola. Evidently, though, I can't find a way to make it smooth; instead, I end up with the boxy plot in red below using code along these lines:

```
plot(points, ylim=c(40,60), pch = 20, col = 2, cex = 2)
fit = loess(points ~ c(1:4), bw=nrd0, na.rm=T)
lines(predict(fit), lwd=2, col= 2)
```

I wonder if there is any way of making the corners smooth, so that it looks more like the blue line...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the message you got, `loess` is not happy with so little points. But you can get a nice curve using `spline`:

```
points = c(60, 46, 46, 60)
plot(points, ylim=c(40,60), pch = 20, col = 2, cex = 2)
lines(spline(1:4, points, n=100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to fit a quadratic you can get what you want as follows.
Assume the quadratic function is

```
f(x) = a*x^2 + b*x + c
```

then we know that

```
a+b+c = 60
4a+2b+c = 46
9a+3b+c = 46
```

by equating `f(1),f(2),f(3)` with `points[1:3]`.
We can ignore the fourth element of `points]` because of symmetry.
The `a,b,c` are the solution of a set of linear equations `A %*% x = points`.
So construct matrix `A` as follows

```
A <- matrix(c(1,1,1,4,2,1,9,3,1),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

and then solve the linear equations:

```
pcoef <- solve(A,points[1:3])
```

Now to get the graph you want do

```
f <- function(x,pcoef)  pcoef[1]*x^2 + pcoef[2]*x + pcoef[3]
g <- function(x) f(x,pcoef)

plot(points, ylim=c(40,60), pch = 20, col = 2, cex = 2)
curve(g,from=1,to=4,add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

[image]